# Container view controllers vs. complex view hierarchies

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

This is an open ended question regarding best practices when creating complex view hierarchies  in an iOS app. For the purposes of this question, I define a complex view hierarchy as one that integrates several models, with several views. For example, on the iPad, you may have a view on the left that controls the content on the view of the right. Each view may have multiple elements (buttons, table views, gestures, animations, behaviours, etc).

You can of course, integrate all these into a single view controller. However, you may be left with a very complex view controller that integrates several loosely related models. Alternatively, you can decompose each view into its respective view/controller pair and add those to a container view controller.

Personally, I favour the use of container view controllers as they allow me to focus my efforts on a single view controller at a time that services a very specific purpose.

Which approach have you chosen and why?

Answer (score 3):

Defenatly the 'Container View Controller'. At my company we used to say "Keep it simple and stupid".  So I think its best to have a View, a ViewController, a Model and a DataController. Where each Function is (at best) not longer then 3 lines of code and each line is no longer then 80 characters. And a Class should be no longer then 400 lines. So it is sure you have all things at their own place, where they belong. Its clear where some thing are done.

Also one Controller do only one Thing. So a NewsletterOrderViewController should only take the Values from eMail and Name textfield and should pass them to a WebServiceController.
At this every Function and every Class should be at the same level of Abstraction.
Wich is by Example of the NewsletterOrderViewController, that the Method, when a Button gets pushed calls Functions like: dataFromForm, sendDataToService. Then inside of dataFromForm you could call stringFromTextField and in this method (finally) [sometextfield getText];. This is a very very simple Example but I hope you understand what I want to say ;)

Of course all this is my personal opinion...

Comment: +1. Generally good advice except strict limits on number of lines in a class seems a little silly. It should be as many lines as it takes to get the job done efficiently while keeping the code readable. In my own opinion of course. :)

Comment: Yes you are right ;) But in my experience, when your class is longer then 400 lines you missed the Keep-it-simple-and-stupid Rule. Off course not in all cases, but most times

Answer (score 1):

Always, always, always use content UIViews for complex viewControllers.  The UIViewController class was built to have the whole screen, and as such should only be used to take up the whole screen except in very well done cases.

And as for your comment about complexity, so long as you put the effort into making each view the best or simplest it can be, then you shouldn't have a patchwork case.

Comment: With iOS 5, Apple has added support for container view controllers. The notion that UIViewController was built "to have the whole screen" is not exactly true anymore.

What are some strategies you employ in making your content views as simple as possible? For example, if you have multiple table views in your view hierarchy, do you make the view controller the delegate and datasource for each object, or do you assign a new object as the data source/delegate. Or do you go a step further and define a custom subclass of UIView to contain the table view and its data source and delegate?

Comment: My strategy is: Unless you have the man power or the hours to make a complex view hierarchy work as well as a simple one, don't even think about it.  Quality over quantity always